# Cordova WebView, opening InAppBrowser and posting a form at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

With Cordova and using the inAppBrowser say opening a window on an iphone.  How can I POST a form into that new window instance at the same time.  It seems I can open an external or local HTML file using a GET request but I can't post data into that new page.  I want to do the following.  But this gets unexpected behavior, it looks like it opens multiple windows over and over.  Also, if I change the code in anyway, it won't post the form.

```
var ref = $window.open('modules/life/views/cordovaAutoParamed.html', target, options);             
                    if (ref !== undefined && ref !== null) {
                      ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {});
                      ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {});
                      ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {                        
                      });
                      ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
                          ref.show();
                          var fullAutoPostParamed = ' window.document.open(\'text/html\', \'replace\'); \
                            window.document.write(\'<html><body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">  \'); \
                            window.document.write(\' <form action="'+paramed.callbackUrl+'" method="post">  \'); \
                            window.document.write(\'   <input type="hidden" name="Assertion" value="123" />  \'); \
                            window.document.write(\'   <input type="submit" value="execute" />  \'); \
                            window.document.write(\' </form></body></html>  \'); \
                            window.document.close();';
                          paramedLogger.error(fullAutoPostParamed);*/
                          ref.executeScript({code: fullAutoPostParamed });                                                  
                        ref.show();                        
                      });
```

Also, the executeScript doesn't seem to work on a regular browser like Chrome on a desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should call only `window.document.write` functions and no `window.document.open` (the current document is the document that will contain the form).

Then, remove the `body onload` function and add an id to your form:

```
<form id="myform">
```

In the end, after your `ref.executeScript` add another call:

```
ref.executeScript({code: 'document.myform.submit();'})
```

to post the form.

**About the infinite loop:**
I don't know why you're calling `show()` so many times, docs says that the method:

> Displays an InAppBrowser window that was opened hidden. Calling this has no effect if the InAppBrowser was already visible.

**About the executeScript method:**
[Docs says](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowserexecutescript) that it works also in the browser. Please check your console logs for information about that. Also try to check the execution flow of your code using the browser's debugger tools.

Comment: Looks about right.  I still didn't get the browser version working.